# Commerce rules not showing in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-commerce, commerce, drupal-rules

I am currently working on a Drupal8 website where I want to sell user roles. I tried Ubercart with role assignment, but this didn't worked out. I found a tutorial where this was done with Commerce (drupal 7: https://vimeo.com/33808828), but I don't have the right rules to trigger these actions. In my rules module, I don't see any event's linked to commerce. Does anyone know how to help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Drupal Commerce 8.x-2.0+ doesn't rely anymore on Rules, it uses events and transitions instead (Symfony way) : https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/adapting-from-1x/commerce-without-rules.

You'll have to subscribe to events in a custom module, it sounds far more flexible (and efficient) than Rules (which is still great...). Working on a Drupal 8 migration (from D7 with Drupal Commerce), it seems that many things have changed (in the right direction AFAIK).